# Populate a Listview NOT in the current layout

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I'm using the popular SlidingMenu library, and the only thing in it is a listview. So I tried using an array adapter to populate it with an ArrayList that I have, but it gives me a NullPointer Exception. So I had a gut feeling that I should try to set the layout of the *activity* to the layout with the listview, and sure enough, it worked. but that doesn't solve my problem because I need the listview in the DRAWER. Can someone help?

```
package josh.hutchins.frcmatchscouter2014;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    BlueAllianceHandler bah = new BlueAllianceHandler("sc");
    FileIoHandler fih = new FileIoHandler(/*maybe pass in folder path here?*/);

    ArrayList<String> testTeams = new ArrayList<String>();

     ListView drawerListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerListView);


       setupSlidingMenu();
       //Toast.makeText(this, bah.pullData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       pullTeamData();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    void setupSlidingMenu(){
        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);
    }

    void pullTeamData(){
        //JUST FOR TESTING PURPOSES
        testTeams.add("2655");
        testTeams.add("1533");
        testTeams.add("900");
        testTeams.add("4451");
        testTeams.add("2200");
        testTeams.add("3301");
        testTeams.add("2059");
        testTeams.add("5010");
        testTeams.add("1747");
        testTeams.add("2641");
        testTeams.add("4231");

        fih.createTeamRecords(testTeams);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                testTeams );

        drawerListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting a NPE?

Comment: @zgc7009 Sorry... should have included that. At the very end: drawerListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

Comment: Just tested it, I'm not getting any errors...

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these steps :

1.Extend SlidingFragmentActivity in your MainActivity instead of just Activity.

2.Make two layouts of FrameLayout type in your layout folder, like this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/menu_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

name layouts as menu_frame, content_frame ,menu_frame will hold the list view that you require and content_frame will hold the content.

3.In your MainActivity , do this.

```
SlidingMenu menu;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new MenuFragment()).commit();

    setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, new ShockFeedsFragment()).commit();

    ab=getActionBar();

    menu = getSlidingMenu();
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffset(200);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT );
}
```

1. Now design the layout for your left menu , just simply include a listview in a linear layout and name your layout as left_menu.
2. Make a fragment named MenuFragment , extend ragment class , in onCreateView Method , setup your menu list view as shown below

   ```
       @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.left_menu, container, false);
   lv=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.menuListView);
   iv=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageMenuProfile);
   tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewProfileName);
   LeftMenuAdapter adap=new LeftMenuAdapter(getActivity(), list);
   //lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.ledt_en_row,R.id.textList,new String[] {"H","R","S","B","C","W"}));
   lv.setAdapter(adap);
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new MenuListListener());

   return v;
   }
   ```

I have implemented the same library , did it this way , working perfectly , hope it does same for you :)... good luck.